# Do URL sortneres make an impact on search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, google, url, google-search, url-shorteners

Can anyone explain me what does the following mean (from [thesearchenginepros](http://www.thesearchenginepros.com/top-7-advantages-of-using-url-shorteners.html)):

```
The best URL shorteners will use a 301 redirect to pass along their Google page rank
to the destination web address. This helps the redirected web address advance in 
search rankings.
```

I was going through the advantages of shortened url, when I came across this.

Answer (score 0):

The idea mentioned there, is that when a link is followed to a site, for instance, tinyurl.com it gets some value, or "juice", if that site redirects the link with a 301 to another site, it passes some of the value to that other site (final destination of the link).

Is it valuable?, not much.

Using a shortener when you need to save space is very good, but that's it, there is no reason to used them if you can avoid it. There are many drawbacks that also affect the value of your site and links to use a shortener just for the sake of it.

There is a video on Youtube, [Are shortened URLs treated differently than other redirects?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kd4QA21JMQo) that has been linked on some resources related to the subject where Matt Cutts talks briefly about that. As he mentions, those links are treated as any other link, which means that they keep some value.

**Update, simplified version**

Every site has a value, consider each link on site A that points to a site B a little transfer of value, like money on people's account.

When you click a link, you are clicking a fragment of text that describes what is going to be on the other side of the link, so when you click a link on Site A because they mention that there is something interesting on site B, site A is sending a bit of value to Site B.

If the piece of text that you clicked on site A doesn't have the address of site B, but a URL from a shortener service, then Site A passes some value to the shortener service, and then the shortener service, who is doing a 301 redirection to site B, passes some value to them.

Comment: I seriously didn't understand your first stanza

Comment: also..you mention _"..There are many drawbacks that also affect the value of your site and links to use a shortener just for the sake of it.."_  when you also write  _"..As he mentions, those links are treated as any other link, which means that they keep some value.."_ This is a contradiction

Comment: Added a simplified version. And no, there is no contradiction, there is a lot more to value on sites and links that 301 redirections. Consider delay on following the link, or the disappearance of the shortener service, or the loss of meaningul words on the link.

Comment: I have seen some big brands using a shortener on their facebook and  google plus pages. But they use good shorteners like `bit.ly` What is your say on that ?

Comment: As mentioned, they save space, plus, when the URL is visible, it's easier to remember. Although I think almost everybody clicks on them rather than write them down. Also, big brands don't care about relevance of links and linkers, they already have a user base and enough means to improve it.

Comment: yeah..one point

Comment: but when google will index..it will _also_ index the masked url. Am I right ?

Comment: No it won't, since that URL 301 redirects to your site.

Comment: I meant the url to my site